# How to share the Integer type of value in jMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I wrote a Script in Test Case inside BeanShell PreProcessor and I want to use the value(Integer) in ThreadGroup.

By using `vars.put()` we can only share *String* type of values.

**NOTE:** I want to use the value in *Number of Threads(users)* block

[image: Image Link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways of doing this:

1. Use [vars.putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) - places an arbitrary Object into JMeterVariables
2. Cast Integer to String `vars.put("foo", String.valueOf(bar));`
3. Use [bsh.shared namespace](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) like:

   ```
   bsh.shared.myInt = 15
   ```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests

**NOTE!** you won't be able to amend number of threads in the current Thead Group using Beanshell test elements.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I just added an image link. Look into it and tell me. In Beanshell Preprocessor I got a value and I want to use the value (Of course Integer type) in *Number of Threads* block